# Normalize strings related to review audit

Tags: feature-request, review-audits, wording

There is pair of strings related to review audit:

- This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. **You didn't pass.**
- This was only a test, designed to make sure you were paying attention. **You passed.**

I suggest to normalize the terms used in these strings ("audit" vs "test"), or even make the first part (before the bold text) the same.

Comment: The way I see it (Non-native English speaker) the first text containing "Audit" comes off as more serious as the second "only a test", which in my opinion is how it should be. Any confusion between both texts is desirable as if it's the same text chances are a failure will be confused with a pass.